# Filter list view

Tags: 2013, list, view

I have List 1: *Versions* and in it thee are 3 items

1. Version 1 | John Doe
2. Version 2 | Peter Parker
3. Version 3 | John Smith

each item has two columns Title and People picker *Manager*
In List 2: *Requests* users create requests.
Manager from List 1 should only see items in List 2 if column in item has value of version he is responsible of.

So let's say there are 10 items and Peter should only see items which have Version 2 in them.
I know I can do it with WF in SPD, but there is a little problem with this. What would happen if Manager goes to another version, he shouldn't see anymore those items.

I need to make it update/promptly on each opening of list view. So I thought of something like taking Managers from List 1 and putting them in some temporary variable, then on each opening of list view that variable check with current user.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: If the Manager version changes, create a workflow in list1 (run on item change), to loop through all the items in List2 and update the ManagerName if version matches.

Comment: I thought of that, but I was more about something more sophisticate. Something with javascript to see changes on page opening/refresh